# Azure devops - Preparing self hosted test agents

Tags: azure-devops, automated-tests, ui-automation, build-automation, testcomplete

What is the best way to create a list of Self-hosted agents in Azure Devops (In order to run Automated tests with Smartbear TestExecute) without doing all the steps manually ?

Let's assume that there will be 40-50 PCs running Windows 10 which have to be made an agent and linked with the Azure pipelines.

I'm looking for a way to avoid doing these steps 50 times:

1. Create these agents manually by following all the steps here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops and then
2. Install TestExecute on each of them

Is there a Template that one can create and run to Implement this ?

Comment: If you do not want to download package and configure self hosted agents manually, use the Rest Api [Agents - Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agents/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), however, the request body of this api might be complex to impelement. Also, as suggested in the api doc,configure an agent using the agent download package should be a better choice, you might need to repeat it but it's easy to operate.

Answer (score 1):

The `--unattended` option mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#unattended-config) should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of automating your test environment, probably you can take a look at Ansible: [win_package](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_package_module.html), [Ansible extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.vss-services-ansible&targetId=3c00faad-1397-4c67-aa9e-79ec3f527ea8)

Haven't tried it myself, but maybe you could install the downloaded agent, run the PS scripts and then install the Smartbear TestExecute inside one playbook.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [installing TestExecute in silent mode](https://support.smartbear.com/testexecute/docs/general-info/installing/installing-in-silent-mode.html) from the command line to avoid doing that manually. As for configuring agents, the test agent deployment task is now deprecated, so it looks like there's no way to skip doing that.